# DocumentDb Compound Query really slow for Date

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb

I am using DocumentDb database(total size ~13TB)
This is the schema of the database, all the keys are single indexed

```
[
    {
      {key : {"customerId" : 1}},
      {key : {"typeOfProduct" : 1}},
      {key : {"date": 1}},
    }
]
```

**1st query:** `db.collectionName.find({"customerId" : <SAMPLE-CUSTOMER>}).count()`
*returns 500 documents*

**2nd query:** `db.collectionName.find({"customerId" : <SAMPLE-CUSTOMER>, "typeOfProduct" : <TYPE>}).count()`
*returns 200 documents*

**3nd query** `db.collectionName.find({"customerId" : <SAMPLE-CUSTOMER>, "date" : { "$gte" : NumberLong(1584055385383), "$lte" : NumberLong(1584141785383)}}).count()`
*query just keeps on running infinitely*

In the 2nd query, My understanding is that DocumentDb first gets all the documents for matching `customerId` which is 500, and then iteratively searches for matching `typeOfProduct` through each document.

In the 3rd query, it is supposed to be working in a similar manner, but the query keeps on running infinitely.

Can someone explain why this is happening? Why is it so slow with the Date? Is it because of the size of the database or am I writing the query wrong?

Comment: Can you provide sample data please

Comment: Sample Data
```{
    "customerId" : 12345678,
    "typeOfProduct": "Clothing",
    "date": NumberLong("1562084180175")
}```

Comment: Try to run with `.hint({customerId: 1})`, should help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have one three-field index (1) or three single-field indexes (2).

1. Both first and second query uses that index because they're [prefix-matching](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes) it. In general, the third query could use the index easily, *skipping* the second field. You can check it using [`explain()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html).
2. It's not obvious how Mongo will pick the index, but knowing your data structure, you can suggest one, using [`hint(index)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/index.html) (`{customerId: 1}` in your case). To check which one is being used for this query by default, use [`explain()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html).

Comment: I am using three Single Field Index.
Also, I cannot use `explain()` because documentDb API does not support it.

Comment: Then try using `hint` with the preferred index (`{customerId: 1}` should work).